# How can I combine a multiple videos into one single video and set the position of them using Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

My problem is that, I have 4 videos and I would like to combine and fit them into one single video and play them at once using Python. Each of the video are set in the position (e.g. top, bottom, left, right) like a hologram video [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HRHf.jpg). Are there any ways which can help me implement this? I've found some related source which is similar to my problem but I cannot manage to apply it for my problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! you should try to post the original 4 images, and what have you tried so far and what went wrong. The question now it is a little broad, since it can be done in many ways depending on what you have as input and what you want to tried. For instance, you can just concatenate the images with numpy, or write a black image and copy each of them where you want. Maybe [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/22/writing-to-video-with-opencv/) turial can inspire you.

Comment: I've been trying according to this link [link](https://github.com/eokeeffe/Pyramid-Hologram-Generator/blob/master/3DHologram.py) which similar to what I want but I've got an error and some lack of understanding in the line of code. According to @api55 , I thought about the idea of creating a black image and attach each of the video into that image but I have no idea on how to do it. The link you gave to me helped me understand more on writing a video using opencv but could you provide a  way to do that (writing a black image and copy each of them where you want). Thank you:))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to merge all images together by copying them into one black frame. Here is an example with the same image in all 4 places:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#loads images and gets data
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
h,w,_ = img.shape    

# creates the resulting image with double the size and 3 channels 
output = np.zeros((h * 2, w * 2, 3), dtype="uint8")

# copies the image to the top left
output[0:h, 0:w] = img 
# copies the image to the top right
output[0:h, w:w * 2] = img 
# copies the image to the bottom left
output[h:h * 2, w:w * 2] = img 
# copies the image to the bottom right
output[h:h * 2, 0:w] = img
```

You can always change the img to something different. Also you can concatenate them like this:

```
top = np.hstack((img, img))
bottom = np.hstack((img, img))
result = np.vstack((top, bottom))
```

And the result will be the same.

Here as sample of the resulting img with this code:
[image]

However your image is a little bit different, you will need a rotation and is not exactly concatenation, but the copying one. An example of this follows:

```
# creates the resulting image with double the size and 3 channels 
output = np.zeros((w+h+h , w + h + h, 3), dtype="uint8")

# top img
output[0:h, h:h+w] = img 
# left img (rotated 90°)
output[h:h+w, 0:h] = np.rot90(img,1) 
# right img (rotated 270°)
output[h:h + w, h + w:h +w +h] = np.rot90(img,3)  
# bottom img (rotated 180°)
output[h+w:h+w+h, h:h+w] = np.rot90(img,2)
```

and the result is like this:

[image]

If you use your image with the black background you will get more or less what you have there. You would need to play maybe with the copying parameters, but basically you do something like:

```
imgToCopyTo[y1:y2, x1:x2] = imgToCopyFrom
```

Where y1 and x1 is your top left coordinates where you want to start the copy and y2 and x2 are your bottom right coordinates of where you want to copy to. Also y2-y1 should have the height of the imgToCopyFrom x2-x1 the width (it can be bigger than the width or height but not smaller).

Comment: So, if I have 4 different images with different height and width, I should start with scaling them to be the same(for the same value in variable h and w) size and read all the image at once, right?

Comment: @Jamiewp it depends on what you want at the end, in my example the logo has different height than width (428 x 378), that is why I used things like `h:h + w, h + w:h +w +h` in my code, which mixes heights and widths to get the correct place. However if you need them square or different scale you can resize it first and then merge them, just remember that to avoid stretching the image, keep the same ratio and crop it to match.

Comment: Sorry but I really need help. Since, I want to use 4 different videos which each of them might have different frame resolution so I don't know how to apply the value of w and h in the output  and I really have a trouble using a VideoCapture for all 4 videos.  This is the link about the problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/52278770/6714341  Can you please help me with that?