# VideoCapture() to read multiple videos and frame resolution problem

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

According to the answer from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052480/how-can-i-combine-a-multiple-videos-into-one-single-video-and-set-the-position-o) which refer to the way to combine single image into a 4 side. From there, I want to change from using only single video to use 4 videos as an input.

This is my code which used single video as an input

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def make4side(image, scale=0.5):

   # image = cv2.imread(image)
   h = int((scale*image.shape[0])) #height
   w = int((scale*image.shape[1])) #width
   image = cv2.resize(image, (w,h ), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) #shrink image to half

   output = np.zeros((w+h+h , w + h + h, 3), dtype="uint8")

   # top 
   output[0:h, h:h+w] = image 
   # left >> rotate 90
   output[h:h+w, 0:h] = np.rot90(image,1) 
   # right >> rotate 270
   output[h:h + w, h + w:h +w +h] = np.rot90(image,3)  
   # bottom >> rotate 180
   output[h+w:h+w+h, h:h+w] = np.rot90(image,2) 

   return output
   #cv2.imwrite('test.jpg', output)

def process(video):
   cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
   holo = None
   ret = False
   while(not ret):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        holo = make4side(frame)
   out = cv2.VideoWriter('hologram640x480.avi',fourcc, 23.98, (holo.shape[0],holo.shape[1]))
   total_frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
   count = 0
   print("Processing %d frames"%(total_frames))
   while(True):
       # Capture frame-by-frame
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       if ret:
           frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
           holo = make4side(frame)
           out.write(holo)
           count += 1
           print("Total:%d of %d"%(count,total_frames))
       if(count>=total_frames-1):
           break

   cap.release()
   out.release()
   return

process('g.mov')
```

the result is like this.

[image: 4 sided video from single video]

In this code, the overall frame's height and width are based only on the input which is the single video which I concern on this too since I use 4 videos and of course the frame resolution are not the same (but all are landscape). Variables h and w in the function make4side() are the main part that help positioning each of the small frame. So for this case, what should the big frame (variable output) resolution be?

I have to read 4 videos and write it into one so, how can I use VideoCapture object to do it for this purpose

To make my question clear, I want to have a single video that consist of 4 input videos, each of them are going to be placed at each of the position (top, bottom, left and right). I have a problem with the big frame resolution which I don't know what to use if I have 4 videos instead of one. Another problem is about the VideoCapture object. How can I read frames of all videos at the same time or any other way to do this?

Thank you

Edit:
[image: top]
top side

[image: left]
left side

[image: back]
back side

[image: right]
right side

These are not the real frames I will be used but just a simple idea what I am going to use for my video. Another thing, input files may not have the same resolution. How can I use many videocapture objects to read each of them and place it on each side of the big frame to write a single video

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question completely. What is not doing right? I mean, until now your big image has a shape of (w+h+h , w + h + h, 3) with respect to your w and h. Do you want it to make each small image square first?

Comment: I want to read 4 videos and place each of it to each side ( one vid, one side) to become one single video but the problem is that I cannot find a way to read all of it. And the size of the big frame changed which I resize it in the process() function (not w+h+h)to be a rectangle, w and h is not a frame resolution of the one video anymore so there will need to be changed in variable output which I cannot find a way to calculate it

Comment: The code above is just for a single video as an input, but my point here is that I want to changed them to be 4 videos for each of the side. Btw, the code in edit 2 is error, I am just trying but it did not work

Comment: Ahhh ok, now I get it. Probably the answer is to make them all similar by cropping/resizing first... I may answer you better on saturday :( If no one answers first

Comment: Edit from my previous comment: I mean 4 videos input but one video for each of the side e.g. video A on top, video B go left, C go right and D at the bottom. I have been trying a week to find a way to use many videocapture objects to apply to this but cannot find one. Thank you for help in advance

Comment: hello, sorry for disturbing but need help here :)) @api55

Comment: sure, can you edit your question and add the 4 images in question (one for each video) I just want to be able to get the correct results :)

Comment: Right now I did not have the raw video taken by each side (the video recording setup plan is not done) basically it is the video of a presenter standing and each video show each side of the presenter(front,back,left and right) I just testing with a random landscape videos.

Comment: Don't worry about the uncorrect side of images. Multiple videocapture objects for each video and side is the blank thing I did not know how to apply with the make4side() function

Comment: I added some testing images for you @api55

Comment: I reseached from the internet about multiple videocapture objects such that I may have to use multi-threading. I just knew only the simple idea of it.  Do we have another approach for doing this despite of multi-threading? @api55

Comment: just give me some time to make the answer... If it is video I would not use multithreading, if it is webcams maybe... but it depends on what you want to do. For getting 4 images and resizing you can do it in the same thread with 4 different VideoCapture objects.

Comment: I am really sorry. I just trying to find any possible way of doing it. I am really sorry @api55

Answer (score 2):

So everything depends on what you want to do, so it will come on what type of images you will be processing. First of all, you can always have 4 instances of the VideoCapture class, and each of them loads a new video, something like:

```
videoTop = cv2.VideoCapture(videoTopFileName)
videoLeft = cv2.VideoCapture(videoLeftFileName)
videoRight = cv2.VideoCapture(videoRightFileName)
videoBottom = cv2.VideoCapture(videoBottomFileName)

readCorrect = True
while( readCorrect ):
  readCorrect , topFrame = videoTop.read()
  ret, leftFrame = videoLeft.read()
  readCorrect = readCorrect and ret
  ret, rightFrame = videoRight.read()
  readCorrect  = readCorrect and ret
  ret, bottomFrame = videoBottom.read()
  readCorrect = readCorrect and ret
  if readCorrect :
     holo = make4side(topFrame, leftFrame, rightFrame, bottomFrame )
```

You can in this loop already save your image in the VideoWriter.

Now it comes the tricky part, your images are not of equal size... you can do something like:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load images, in your case frames from videos
top = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\1.jpg")
left = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\2.jpg")
bottom = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\3.jpg")
right = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\4.jpg")

targetSize = (200,200)

h = targetSize[1] #height
w = targetSize[0] #width

top = cv2.resize(top,  targetSize )
left = cv2.resize(left,  targetSize )
bottom = cv2.resize(bottom,  targetSize )
right = cv2.resize(right,  targetSize )

output = np.zeros((w+h+h , w + h + h, 3), dtype="uint8")

# top
output[0:h, h:h+w] = top
# left >> rotate 90
output[h:h+w, 0:h] = np.rot90(left,1)
# right >> rotate 270
output[h:h + w, h + w:h +w +h] = np.rot90(bottom,3)
# bottom >> rotate 180
output[h+w:h+w+h, h:h+w] = np.rot90(right,2)

cv2.imshow("frame", output )
cv2.waitKey(0)import cv2
import numpy as np

# load images, in your case frames from videos
top = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\1.jpg")
left = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\2.jpg")
bottom = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\3.jpg")
right = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\4.jpg")

targetSize = (200,200)

h = targetSize[1] #height
w = targetSize[0] #width

top = cv2.resize(top,  targetSize )
left = cv2.resize(left,  targetSize )
bottom = cv2.resize(bottom,  targetSize )
right = cv2.resize(right,  targetSize )

output = np.zeros((w+h+h , w + h + h, 3), dtype="uint8")

# top
output[0:h, h:h+w] = top
# left >> rotate 90
output[h:h+w, 0:h] = np.rot90(left,1)
# right >> rotate 270
output[h:h + w, h + w:h +w +h] = np.rot90(bottom,3)
# bottom >> rotate 180
output[h+w:h+w+h, h:h+w] = np.rot90(right,2)

cv2.imshow("frame", output )
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But this generates a "bad" image like this one:

[image]

To make it not distorted, you should find the aspect ratio and try to resize them something similar. In case that the aspect ratio is different, then you will have to pad the images. This is the part that depends on your task, you can crop the image or pad it.

But basically that is what should be done. I hope this helps you.

---

**Update:**

Just to clarify the loop part:

```
  readCorrect , topFrame = videoTop.read()
  ret, leftFrame = videoLeft.read()
  readCorrect = readCorrect and ret
```

In the first line I assigned to the `readCorrect` variable the boolean return from `read`. Then in the next image I assigned to `ret` and do a logic `and` with the previous result. This way you know if all of them are true, or if ANY is false.

I also corrected something in the loop that had a mistake (I put while not readCorrect and it should be without the not).

One more thing before the loop you should create the VideoWriter object, you can always get the sizes of each video before reading with the [`get`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get) with the argument `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH` and `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT`, like `videoTop.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)`.

And then inside the loop, specifically inside the if after getting the image you can write it to.

Comment: Could you explain the code in the while loop below the videocapture object (the readcorrect one) and from that code I add something like `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
     out = cv2.VideoWriter('vidname.avi',fourcc, 23.98, (holo.shape[0],holo.shape[1]))
     out.write(holo)
     out.release()` after the last line of that loop to write a video. There's no error but the written video seem to have just only one frame. What am I doing wrong here

Comment: I just do read 4 times, and check that all return true (previous result AND new result), if all return true you can do the 4 sided image. You only have 1 image because you need to create the VideoWriter **before** the loop and inside the loop add the image

Comment: But if I put it before the loop, how can I know the frame size of the videowriter >> holo.size[0] and holo.size[1]

Comment: @Jamiewp See my updated answer, you can use the `get` function to get the sizes... however if you use a fix size in the resize like in my example you can know it too (in my example is 600x600 -> (h+w+h, h+w+h))

Comment: I also updated the line before the while (it was false and no it is true), maybe it is due to that and does not enter the loop and makes something weird... with the not and the false, it will enter only once (the next iter, it will be true)

Comment: Oh, I forgot about it. This work pretty well. I just realized that I put `out.release()` in the loop, that's why it read only the first frame. Thank you so much for helping me out.